# Algorithm for retrieving all the permutations (randomized) for a vector sequence 1...N with only unique values

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

Here is the problem: I have a vector of $N$ elements long (containing only **unique** values from $1...N$).

1. I am searching for an algorithm to obtain all the (randomized) combinations possible, where each value can only appear once.

That is for instance the following vectors in case $N=3$.

$(1, 2, 3)$

$(1, 3, 2)$

$(2, 1, 3)$

$(2, 3, 1)$

$(3, 1, 2)$

$(3, 2, 1)$

*Any more?*

**Follow up questions:**

1. Is there a way to filter out rules that seem to be systematic, for example the vector $(1,2,3,4)$, as I am only searching for randomized combinations.
2. How many combinations are there possible? Is it 100x100?
3. Is there a built-in **Matlab** function available for this?

Comment: What do you call a **randomized** combination? (actually, permutation, see my answer below) I can imagine taking a random permutation (see [Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)), but not *filtering* random permutations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) but [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). There are $n!$ permutations of $(1,2,\cdots,n)$, with $n!=1\cdot2\cdots n$.

There is a very simple algorithm to get them, one at a time, in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (that is, the order you use in your example).

Start with a permutation $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$, we want the next one in lexicographic order.

1. Find the smallest index $i$ such that the sequence $(a_i,a_{i+1},\cdots,a_n)$ is decreasing.
2. If $i=1$, you are done, because the whole permutation is decreasing, and it's the last.
3. Reverse this sequence $(a_i,a_{i+1},\cdots,a_n)$, so that it's now increasing.
4. Exchange $a_{i-1}$ with $a_j$, where $j$ is the smallest index, such that $j\geq i$ and $a_j>a_{i-1}$. You have then the next permutation.

See [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations) for several implementations. For Matlab, you have the [perms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) function.

You will find this algorithm and other ones in Knuth's [TAOCP volume 4 fasc. 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201853930). The whole volume 4 is about combinatorial algorithms.